# How do I convert time from a string format to "Linux Time"?

Tags: php, date

I currently have a date in the format

```
20/10/2000 2:2:02
```

I need this date to be in "Linux Time" so that I can use it with other functions.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the format the date is saved as.

How can I convert this to Linux Time?

Comment: Note .. i inserting the date to my database as (20/10/2000 2:2:02) so my question is how to convert from (20/10/2000 2:2:02) to linux format

Comment: See the MySQL [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) Function, it does what you're looking for. The value returned can be used with `date()` for format it according to your needs.

Comment: Yes that exactly what i want .. , how i can use the reterned value from (strtodate function) in date() function ?

Comment: For example : i got this (int(972003722)) .. now how i can use 972003722 in date() function ?

Comment: i tested this code echo date('d-m-Y','0313844177'); and it's working fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function "strtotime" takes a date in a string format (exactly what you have in the database) and converts it to epoch time (which you've referred to as linux time)

An example

```
<?php 
$time = '20-10-2000 2:2:02';
var_dump(strtotime($time));
```

Outputs

```
int(972003722)
```

strtotime() uses american dates (MM/DD/YY) if you use /'s and English dates (DD/MM/YY) if you use dashes - so for you you'd need

```
<?php 
$time = str_replace('/', '-', '20/10/2000 2:2:02');
var_dump(strtotime($time));
```

Comment: This answer should be voteup .. not down , very useful for me ! now i am able to make (3 days ago) time format . but how to get the month name from this date format 20-10-2000 2:2:02

Comment: Osama, feel free to accept the answer! (and you're probably better asking a second question for that one!)

Comment: (and the vote down was because the other person answering didn't like that I'd voted down on their answer and told them that they'd not answered the question.  So they voted me down - then deleted their answer.  Petty)

Comment: I am sorry to have caused a problem for you .. your answer was very useful

Comment: Osama, you didn't cause a problem :)

Comment: Now problem fixed and i am able to do what i want .. and you'r was the reason to fix my problem .. thank you very much and i hope no more problems for you .. and sorry for my english :(